# After altering a migration file's table, how do I update my database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, clustered-index, entity-framework-migrations

I have my initial migrations file that has all the entity tables in it and the database is updated and has all tables.
Now I want to alter a table and change the clustered index from the primary key to another index. Code modifications shown below.
I made two small changes here, setting clustered to false for primary key and true for another index. Not sure if this will work because now I get an error when trying to update the database.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.YogaSpaceEvents",
            c => new
                {
                    YogaSpaceEventId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    DateTimeScheduled = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    AppointmentLength = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    StatusEnum = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    YogaSpaceRefId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.YogaSpaceEventId, clustered: false)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.YogaSpaces", t => t.YogaSpaceRefId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.DateTimeScheduled, clustered: true)
            .Index(t => t.YogaSpaceRefId);
```

If I run update-database I get an error saying "the entity 'blahblah' already exists in the database". It's coming from the first "CrateTable" statement in the migration file. What are the steps to update the database with my changes in the migration file? Do I need to create another migration file with just the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit an existing migration and have it apply without updating down to that migration then re-updating back up to the latest. This way, you run all of the `Down()` scripts, which removes the table.

Alternatively, you construct a new migration and explicitly do the operation(s) required in the `Up()` and reverse them in the `Down()`.

Answer (score 0):

You overestimated migrations mechanism. It's purpose is to manage database transitions between consecutive migrations, it is not clever enough to recognise your changes within migration code. Normally to change database structure you have to generate new migration with code altering tables, columns, indexes etc. to match new structure. With IndexAttribute (ver. 6.1) you may define index on DateTimeScheduled to be clustered and EF will automatically recognize that model changed and when you will use add-migration it will generate migrations altering YogaSpaceEvents for you.

If you insist that you do not want to have a separate migration but the changes should be included in the current one you have 2 options:

1. Migrate your database to previous migration, use "add-migration -Force" to regenerate the current migration to match your changes and then apply migration to your database
2. With "add-migration" add new migration applying your changes to db. Then migrate your database to the newest state. After that delete your newly added migration file, with "add-migration -Force" applied on some test database regenerate your initial migration to incorporate with it your changes to the model. The last thing to do is to delete in database __MigrationsHistory table row corresponding to your deleted migration and update "Model" field value of thr row corresponding to initial migration to value of "Model" field from row corresponding to deleted migration.

In your case probably 1) option won't work as you are changing your first migration so reverting it would cause removing all db structure and all db data with it. But if your db do not still contain any important data this is easier way. If you want to preserve data and have only 1 migration you have to use path 2).

Comment: hi. Maybe I can rephrase my question to - how do I alter a table in a migration file? I can say "add-migration ChangeIndex" and create a new file. In that file I would like to change some tables indexes (ex. remove cluster on primary key to another index), then update-database.

Comment: As far as I know clustered index on the table maybe set only when it is being created. EF migrations engine is not wise enough to recognise that. So in your case you will be forced to delete YogaSpaceEvents table (instruction DropTable) and create it once again with provided by you CreateTable instruction. Of course you will need to drop any foreign key relation referring your table as well before dropping. If you want to save your data from YogaSpaceEvents then instead of dropping change it name with RenameTable, then Create new table, copy the data with Sql function and drop the old table.